# Any updated marketplace and nft contract based on SmartPy and Taquito

Tags: tezos-client, smartpy, blockchain

```
const mintNFT = async ({ amount, metadata }) => {
  const response = await checkIfWalletConnected(wallet);

  try {
      const tezos = new TezosToolkit(rpcURL);
      tezos.setWalletProvider(wallet);
      const contract = await tezos.wallet.at(config.contractAddress);
      console.log(contract);
      let bytes = "";
      for (var i = 0; i < metadata.length(); i++) {
        bytes += charCodeAt(i).toString(16).slice(-4);
      }
      const op = await contract.methods.mint(amount, bytes).send();
      await op.confirmation();
      fetchData();
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
  }
};
```

Please provide your updating version of the [marketplace tutorial](https://tezos.com/developers/tutorials/nft-markeplace/). How can I call this, it shows error please provide solution of mint function. I'm stuck between the hackathon. Please provide some relevant solutions.

Comment: Please edit your question and format the code in a code block so its easy readable. And please tell what errors do you get? And from what documentation is this code?

Comment: You are probably referring to this tutorial:
https://tezos.com/developers/tutorials/nft-markeplace/
And this associated code:

Comment: Hi Shreyansh, welcome to the tezos stackexchange. You posted an "answer" to your own question, that was intended as a response to Jordan. Jordan would not get any automatic notifications from this, as you replied to yourself, not him. I've deleted that answer and converted it to a comment on Jordan's answer instead

Comment: When posting questions on stackoverflow, please always use the code formatting tools so that the code you post is readable (which it currently is not). When your problem includes encountering an error, please ALWAYS post details of the error itself. The message you get, the line of code etc

Answer (score 0):

You are probably referring to this tutorial:
https://tezos.com/developers/tutorials/nft-markeplace/

You'll find the whole code [here](https://github.com/NishantChandla/nft-marketplace-tutorial/blob/main/src/actions/index.js#L146).

The smart contract's code is [here](https://smartpy.io/ide?code=eJy9V21v4kYQ_s6v2PpL7KvlAGm4KhJSuetRVQo010TNh1O0WswCBtvr7q4TSNX_3tkXv2HDRSddrQgc7@zjeWaemR2iJGNcIpEQLrMDIgKJrDedDNEYboKIBZE2wCLkUSbxirME5zx2nY2Umbi5vLQ7wfRS0iSLiaTickWGOI4WQXZwvF4vjIkQ6IHtaOoCdDBZJlHqI3U7i1I5X0nzz5QM4d676SG4lnSFMI7SSGLsChqvfETMvnfvdi@Er4U1VFe1OzjaUxo3bLUHx6YavnR3RviOSuATUhci8ZGlkpPwjHdS8fNRQiVZEkkKvMpJZRaoLW75SF1639jsbiwUSOMSsrGs4ccmJo0FvQdcXkRrnJCs@Tb9xh09KIOHOZF@e_WZxDnV63_SkPFlG0BdGxYvKddmk@WSUyHaUNrNXG7YW@wSlqdS281ySV@7rXSYcLQ87b66QhbHNJRkERseHxiLPc9vh10h9ZvPQQDq6xfYRyHlB5wx0GiZdIi2tAnPCCdJXYVqDZunpnwebiNxlO1zYZUMn49TqQgdJUit@r6XPErXvkb@cIDqOyLqBTE5sFy6rgMvcHzkFDCOV1VFdRca30MreLfGyjcaVnsDK_dajMaOMnW8gGUQWcES6tpgqksVISB_AWjewd9yV_iYdPEvuf@DLi5ubPCD4in613uqCi0LwPVUrCh31Wt1bBIlKrfv@SisuDZrU_NSH1@OaIJMnkxUulyvKuG091UVCJqC9dGq0b7lZP47oda2Z03DuvQfeE69DorFTvTjGA16pbRV0y7jZiQOj@BD9XzV37Bf@uFbn2vqP9ZNqf@a5DVUQ@NI7sW4y7TWD1Sdt4qj1QpaOlffxkSJ3uCB5NVlmdXFe1FQv2gKuEtUcB8rd2tiNsyKUBlOxzaWks2vZtQI6ri48Z48@GvL9nxrsqk_1Z1g1zPl0eqg3Dc@oPH4WPlWg6XsCzUi55GzdD2xUexC_QpQTZmANmfyY_XgmwBNTaEftOxsWSHnXt8A_EQvO10F8FUHQcpTEgv65r2mB6CaK@dzlWeAQ7E@vd@UMAPaTJidh1Qs9UDTyVUbgWMG_k0KgqkhJWuagAnmFManpfguPpodbtH2isJutEEleuUurGI426SbkkSlBwBTNM3TdaTSpWdLgFYktJV1UYQ0JTxiJjFqBRePbGnrjyJGhQ0JQ_Vu1yE1l2HO3XXZ5ILygbWhMevEUTZDx56GRjVFnwRzMxlXJ2U12AWtw6Q@AuQyiqsjELOVnswbx4ETZSs1pX9OHn_e3s2WH5Lps7j_xG4f7@42hL3OR9vfPk_3@91LPruVf03__nQYTRfFYFCGDw6Kpte9xnqwGbiOGZjv1MBci5gdoYFlfaAufWyitul@V5bV8GOH9eL9bfY1Kr1jboGeCav0lQeX6tyDft_rzl5Gwl03jQVZHTiNFi_x9WazXXMir@P3YbKNn0dZ9rLeJKNoe1hnr8M940M@itJwFe7T@P3hil4Wbwi2gqWGoecFPFddRlWn_cGAYMiHA0c3OTgH9yHNZMTSsQO_jvD8jwc8@XX2@9zm8ShJgkrTuOB4A98Yd@vBKELYemdLE98SN_R_Bu5E8E4Qqfw3Z_Y1HvX7uK94tPPuDIZXPw2vnCa8wvTalWUPynZVFUeWW04Qgwaeakc@Ou2Y19bymSOgI1MGcNBvJMsqoNnBjBJrzkFHsNH8D6rbEdg-).

I don't understand the question but the answer is probably there.

Comment: I faced so many issued, when i worked with https://tezos.com/developers/tutorials/nft-markeplace/ . Now i get to know this is that outdated.
Could you help me to find out FA2 contract (non-fungible Token) and taquito library for creating mint function minting nft, But i'm not able to understand how would I be able to create mint function in interaction part. Did you get me?

Comment: It just used these resources and were able to mint.
What I did: open the SmartPy code. Originate the two contracts with the changed admin. Call the set_administrator on the token to set the marketplace as the administrator.
Clone the repo. Change the Taquito version to `^16.0.0` and set the contract's addresses in `src/config/index.js`. `npm install`, `npm run start` and everything was working.
Now, StackExchange is not the right place to discuss this way. Go the the SmartPy and Taquito Telegram channels and ask your questions.

Comment: @Jordan_tez thanks for helping out on this issue. However we need to move away from silo'd single purpose chat rooms on the tezos ecosystem. Developers find it increasingly difficult to navigate tezos as these channels can't be searched/indexed by google. Please don't encourage users to leave this public space and join one of these rooms instead, as the resolution will be lost and won't benefit anyone else. If back / forth via comments gets difficult, there is a chatroom feature on stackexchange. When using it, please always post a final updated answer here afterwards